# Setting up Laravel 5.1 on Digital Ocean Ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, apache, laravel, ubuntu

I'm following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/could-someone-make-a-tutorial-on-how-to-install-laravel-on-ubuntu-16-04-using-lamp) on setting up [Laravel 5.1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation) on Ubuntu (LAMP stack) for Digital Ocean. When I try to access my Laravel app on the one-click droplet, I get:

[image]

I went through the steps of installing Composer then Laravel, and then placed `~/.composer/vendor/bin` directory in my PATH "so the laravel executable can be located by your system."

`root@phpmyadmin-512mb-nyc3-01:/# cat ~/.bashrc`:

```
   echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
   export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

Then follow [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-an-apache-web-root-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04) on changing my webroot so I can serve from `/public` like Laravel expects:

`nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

I change `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/` to `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public`[image]

Then restarted `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

I cannot access my Laravel app. It gives a `500` error. Why is this?

---

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or
>   file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-2017-05-17.log" could not be
>   opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php(106):
>   Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)\n#1
>   /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37):
>   Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler->write(Array)\n#2
>   /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(336):
>   Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)\n#3
>   /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(615):
>   Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(UnexpectedValueException),
>   Array)\n#4
>   /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(202):
>   Monolog\Logger->error(Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)\n#5
>   /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(11
>   in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php
>   on line 107

Comment: i think you may have not change the permission of storage and bootstrap/cache directory.

Comment: @reza what do I need to change it to? `cat`'ing the file shows that it's empty.

Comment: give this directory write permission. check  Directory Permissions section in the following link https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation

Comment: @reza I'm on Laravel 5.1, not 5.4. Does that matter?

Comment: `sudo chown -R :www-data /var/www/laravel` & `sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/laravel/storage` - where laravel is your project name. Also, please add your log files for 500 error.

Comment: @senty error posted

Comment: @Growler yeah, just give storage folder the permission. It should help

Comment: @senty okay this seemed to work: now getting error `production.ERROR: RuntimeException: No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key` despite doing `php artisan key:generate` on the droplet. That didn't work so I also tried copying and pasting the generated key into my `.env` file under `APP_KEY=`

Comment: @senty I also sourced the `.env` file and echo'ed out the values just to double check

Comment: what does `nano .env` say? Is the key present in your .env?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144427/discussion-between-growler-and-senty).

Answer (score 3):

Do you have access to the error log of apache? (or, in case you've defined a custom log file, then check in there). A 500 error will typically leave an entry in the apache log file (/var/log/apache2/error.log) or your custom error log.

In case the error is a permissions issue in writing to "laravel.log", there can be multiple reasons:

1. You haven't given write permissions to your storage or bootstrap/cache directories. Try that.

   ```
   cd /var/www/html/<projectname>
   chmod +777 -R storage
   chmod +777 -R bootstrap/cache
   ```

   You will need to be root to use chmod
2. SELinux does not allow your http user to write to these files (for example, on CentOS). use the following commands from within your application's base directory (the directory that contains your 'app' folder, as well as storage and bootstrap folders:

   ```
   chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t storage
   chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t bootstrap/cache
   ```

In case its SELinux, and your application plans on connecting to MySQL as well, you will also need to run :

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

This is to allow httpd to connect to database. Some locations may try to dissuade the usage of SELinux and tell you to turn it off as a whole, but that is not recommended.

Comment: Error posted above

Comment: That is a permission issue,
 file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-2017-05-17.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php

You should try the steps I've mentioned in my answer, that should solve the problem.